# Wrap Text Silverlight radio button

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Is it possible to have the text in a radio button wrap itself?  For example, I have a border area to work with that's approximately 350 pixels wide and I want to position some radio buttons in there.  I can do that, but when the text is long, I cannot wrap the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

> ```
>     <RadioButton Width="100" >
>         <RadioButton.Content>
>             <TextBlock Text="This is some text that is very long" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
>         </RadioButton.Content>
>     </RadioButton>
> ```